# Is there a way to perform signed division in eBPF?

Tags: linux, networking, division, signed, ebpf

I am trying to perform signed division in eBPF but llvm is throwing unsupported error. Is there a way to perform signed division in any other way (direct/indirect) in eBPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eBPF doesn't have a signed division instruction in its [instruction set](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.17/bpf/instruction-set.html#arithmetic-instructions).

You can still work around it though. Signed division is nothing more than preserving the XOR of the two sides. Meaning, a output is negative if one or the other is negative, but dividing a negative by a negative number gives a positive back.

[This](https://onlinegdb.com/ac8aspdvp) is what I came up with:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int32_t sdiv(int32_t a, int32_t b) {
    bool aneg = a < 0;
    bool bneg = b < 0;
    // get the absolute positive value of both
    uint32_t adiv = aneg ? -a : a;
    uint32_t bdiv = bneg ? -b : b;
    // Do udiv
    uint32_t out = adiv / bdiv;
    // Make output negative if one or the other is negative, not both
    return aneg != bneg ? -out : out;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sdiv(100, 5));
    printf("%d\n", sdiv(-100, 5));
    printf("%d\n", sdiv(100, -5));
    printf("%d\n", sdiv(-100, -5));

    return 0;
}
```

I am sure there are better ways to do it, but this seems to work.